# Assigning a value to variable, stored in a MAP as value

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the following MAP written in groovy

```
def Expected_Value="Jon Doe"
java.util.MAP var1=[node:"username", expected:Expected_Value]
```

Now I want to check if the `Expected_Valu`e is `Jon Doe`, then change it to `Hello World`.
How do i do that using a Map?

I've got the condition as shown below

```
if(var1.get('expected')=="Jon Doe")
{

   \\\\\\\What do i write here\\\\\\\
}
```

Comment: AutomateFr33k, Appreciated up vote for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

You could just assign value as

1. `var1.expected = 'Hello World` or
2. `var1.put('expected', 'Hello World')` or
3. `var1['expected'] = 'Hello World'`

Here is the complete script for reference (just changed variable naming convention for better readablity)

```
def expectedValue = 'Jon Doe'
def map = [node:"username", expected:expectedValue]
map.expected = (map.expected != 'Jon Doe') ?: 'Hello World'
println map
```

Comment: I don't think what you have for example 3 there will work (`var1[expected] = 'Hello World'`).  You probably need quotes around `expected` otherwise it looks like a variable reference.  `var1['expected'] = 'Hello World'`

Comment: In a literal `Map` expression like `[expected: 'Hello World']` the quotes around `expected` are optional.  In your example, `var1[expected] = 'Hello World'`, they are not optional.